# Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected

Tags: laravel, file-upload, storage, show

I'm faced a problem since yesterday in my laravel projet. I have a input file and the file is uploaded in the forder storage/app/public/uploads.
Now when i want to show the file I have this message: "Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected."

```
<td><a class="" style="text-decoration: underline;" href="{{ asset('storage/app/public') }}/uploads/{{ $row->file }}"  target="_blank" style="color:black;font-size:120%">{{ $row->name }}</a></td>
```

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: make sure that $row->file is not empty or is a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the file publicly available.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Run the artisan command `php artisan storage:link`

This will create a symlink from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`

You can then use the Laravel helper to serve the file

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-storage-path

`storage_path('app/public/uploads/' . $row->file)`